# How to prevent swiping on certain are of the slide using swiperjs

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

We are using [`swiperjs`](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) for slide. It is working great but we have `input` inside the slide and it is very hard to fill up the input if users can actually swipe on those. Im wondering if there is a way to prevent the slider sliding if user touchstart on an input.

This is how we init the slider:

```
new Swiper('.slider', {
  resistance: true,
  resistanceRatio: 25,
});
```

The HTML inside the slides includes

```
<input type="text">
<input type='range' min='0' max='11'>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In answering this question encase somebody will have have same issue in the future.

Just add `swiper-no-swiping` class on the elements that is not swipable or change the `noSwipingClass` parameter.

Comment: this solution works, but not disable the mouse wheel swipe...

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS: Here you you can include the 'swiper-no-swiping' class to as explained by the first answer:

```
/*In ReactJS - this is how you would do it.*/
    <Swiper className='theSwiper' 
            slidesPerView={1.1}
            modules={[Autoplay, Pagination]}
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            watchSlidesProgress
            // onSlideChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
            // onReachEnd={() => { console.log("end game")}}
            >
        <SwiperSlide className='eachSlide swiper-no-swiping' >
            /*Place your slides contents*/
        </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```